# Extjs 4 grouped columns header dynamic text modification

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have the following grouped headers grid :

```
var lestore =  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
       proxy: {
                type: 'memory'
                },
        autoDestroy: true,
        data:objstore
    });

 thegrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: lestore,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{text:'date'},{text:'TV',columns:{text:'400',columns:[{text:'tt1'},{text:'tt2'}]}]  ,
        title:'my title'  ,
        selModel: {
            selType: 'cellmodel'
        },
        renderTo: 'gridmpoff',
            plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1}
                )
                 ],

        listeners: {'edit': function(editor,e) {updtitle(editor,e);}
        },
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        },

    });
```

I need to change the columns texts (tt1,tt2 etc)  after the grid creation, without changing the header grouping.

I Tried modifying the columns property, but that doesn't help, only thing that worked so far is a reconfigure which messes with the editor.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS provides `setText` method fo changing the header text.

Refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column

Comment: setText does not exist in grouped headers (which makes sense, since there are many levels of headers, and you can't just set a "column" text)

Answer (score 0):

After so many searches i came up to the idea that ExtJS 4.1 "reconfigure" is buggy and has never been fixed, as it messes with the plugins (the editor in particular), and every fix i found so far targets only a particular use case, mine was just updating the grouped headers labels without touching anything else.

The solution i used is to simply update the dom (while at same time update the columns headers structure for the extjs so that if at some point their bugs are fixed it is simple to switch to reconfigure, settext or whatever), via : thegrid.container.dom.childNodes ....

I hope this helps gettings someone else from this struggle.

This is related : [Using Ext.grid.Panel.reconfigure() breaks the grids RowEditing plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963870/using-ext-grid-panel-reconfigure-breaks-the-grids-rowediting-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
grid.columns[0].ownerCt.setText('Total Number');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but you can use the code Michael posted :

```
grid.columns[0].ownerCt.setText('Total Number');
```

and then use the column name in your groupHeaderTpl and have something like this :

```
{columnName}: {name}
```

This way it will dynamically change it to the values you want.